# Who is Thomas o' Becket" in Tristram Shandy?

Tags: meaning, tristram-shandy, laurence-sterne

Who is Thomas o'Becket in chapter 2, vol.7 of *The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman*?

> So without arguing the matter further with **Thomas o’Becket**, or any one else—

St. Becket is of course dead at the time when Tristram wrote this.

Below is the whole passage for reference.

> ——and I never gave a peep into Rochester church, or took notice of the dock of Chatham, or visited St. Thomas at Canterbury, though they all three laid in my way—— —But mine, indeed, is a particular case——
>
> So without arguing the matter further with Thomas o’Becket, or any one else—I skip’d into the boat, and in five minutes we got under sail and scudded away like the wind.

Thanks!

Comment: "Thomas à Becket" and "Thomas o'Becket" mean exactly the same thing, namely "Thomas of Becket" or "Thomas from Becket". The first is the French-like English of Thomas' own time, and the second is Irish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the full context, in which Tristram is at Dover, on his way for a trip to France, and momentarily wonders if he should first have checked out some of the sights of England:

> Now hang it! quoth I, as I look'd towards the French coast—a man should know something of his own country too, before he goes abroad—and I never gave a peep into Rochester church, or took notice of the dock of Chatham, or visited St. Thomas at Canterbury, though they all three laid in my way—
>
> —But mine, indeed, is a particular case—
>
> So without arguing the matter further with Thomas o'Becket, or any one else—I skip'd into the boat, and in five minutes we got under sail, and scudded away like the wind.

What, then, does he mean by "should"? He feels that he is expected to know a little of his own country before travelling to another, but from whence does this expectation come? My reading of the next paragraph is that he is using Thomas o'Becket as a sort of synecdoche to represent all the sights of England that came into his mind, as well as perhaps representing established thinking which would expect him to see those sights first. In reality, of course, the only person he needs to argue with is himself - but it may be convenient for him to **use another figure to personify the expectation that came to his mind**. Who should he "argue" with about whether or not he should have visited those sites in Kent? Symbolically, why not Thomas o'Becket, who is himself worth visiting as a tourist, and who might be imagined to be "offended" at not being visited.

I haven't read *Tristram Shandy*, but this interpretation seems to fit with the whimsical humour of the character, much better than the idea of the author breaking the fourth wall by referring to his publisher.

Comment: Wow such an interesting interpretation. I never thought about that possibility. Thomas Becket the publisher does appear in the book once but clearly stated as a bookseller.